# How to copy executable file to Docker container using Testcontainers

Tags: java, docker, junit5, testcontainers, localstack

I'm trying to copy an executable initialization bash script `init.sh` to the Localstack Docker container created with Testcontainers (1.13.0) using the JUnit 5 module:

```
@Container
static LocalStackContainer localStack = new LocalStackContainer("0.10.0")
  .withServices(S3)
  .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sh"), "/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh");
```

But inside the created Docker container the file lacks the execute permission (checked with looking at the file permission using `docker exec -it ID /bin/sh`).

On my machine the file has the following permission:

```
$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 xyz  staff  128 Apr 16 20:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 xyz  staff  128 Apr 16 08:43 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 xyz  staff  135 Apr 16 20:14 application.yml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 xyz  staff  121 Apr 16 20:51 init.sh
```

I also tried copying this file with `.withClasspathResourceMapping()` but this takes a binding mode which only offers `READ_ONLY` or `READ_WRITE`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use another [builder](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/859f29d205f88404d7ec290cdaf6e4fb7b8b6ca2/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/utility/MountableFile.java#L96) of `MountableFile` class, which takes the `mode` argument with a posix file mode value to change permission. For example, making the script executable only for the owner:

```
...
.withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init.sh", 0744), "/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh");
```

`0744` is an octal file mode literal which corresponds to `-rwxr--r--` permission.

However I tried the same configuration with Localstack `0.10.8` and initialisation works without even making the script executable.

Comment: no idea why, but it does not copy a thing in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329613/cannot-copy-file-into-testcontainer